# Set property inside custom target

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have a solution I want to build on a CI server containing projects with a custom target like this:

```
<Target Name="CustomTarget">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageOutputDir>C:\Repos\$(Configuration)</PackageOutputDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Unfortunately the `<PackageOutputDir>` is specified in different locations for some projects so I want to set it twice.

On the CI server I want to set this to another directory using `/property:` from msbuild binary like this:

`msbuild my.sln /property:PackageOutputDir=$buildPath\ci-output;CustomTarget.PackageOutputDir=$buildPath\ci-output' does not set the value inside`CustomTarget`. As I do not control the source, I have to pass the values using the commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Can you move your PropertyGroup definition outside of the target? If you do this then the command line provided value will overwrite the value in the definition within your target.

For example

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PackageOutputDir>C:\Repos\$(Configuration)</PackageOutputDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="CustomTarget"> 
        <Message Text="PackageOutputDir is: $(PackageOutputDir)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

With the args

> msbuild go.build /p:PackageOutputDir="Hello
>   World"

Will produce `"Hello World"`

Alternatively, and good practice in MSBuild is to always define your properties as conditional.

The following example will also produce  `"Hello World"` as the property will not be evaulated within the target as it already has a value from the command line.

```
<Target Name="CustomTarget">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PackageOutputDir Condition="'$(PackageOutputDir)' == ''">C:\Repos\$(Configuration)</PackageOutputDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="PackageOutputDir is: $(PackageOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not control the source, so changing is difficult

Comment: You can always place a copy of the target in your own build file - even the csproj if you must - and this will override the the target with the same name from whatever system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
msbuild my.sln /property:PackageOutputDir=$buildPath\ci-output;CustomTarget.PackageOutputDir=$buildPath\ci-output
```

to

```
msbuild my.sln /property:PackageOutputDir=$buildPath\ci-output;PackageOutputDir=$buildPath\ci-output
```

There is essentially no concept of scope when it comes to MSBuild properties, so the `CustomTarget.` qualifier is not necessary and sabotages the intended property value assignment.